# Converting multiple (and different) windows into tabs

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

Fairly new to WPF.

I'm tasked with converting our application with about ten different windows into a single-window, multi-tabbed application. I'd like your input on the most effective way of doing this.

I suppose I *could* do this the most-straightforward way -- copying and pasting a ton of code into the main XAML file. I imagine I'd end up with a gigantic file though, and would like to avoid that.

I should mention that the contents of each tab will be substantially different from each other.

There must be some element of WPF that enables this that I just haven't been able to find. Really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML there are user controls which you can use. That way, you could use one user-control per tab-content and let the main window only contain the tabview and tabitems and some minor logic code.

To achieve that, you can simply copy-paste most of your current window-code in one user control per window. The code base could remain almost the same (if there are no interactions between the windows at least).

There are quite many resources out there containing further details on user controls like [this code-project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W) (a bit old, but the majority of its contents will still apply) or [that MSDN one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol.ASPx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks DHH (I like your user name). I dismissed User Controls at first because they didn't seem right to me. But the more I think about them, the more I like them. I'm going to try this out and see how it goes -- I'll add more detail here on the outcome.

Comment: Just following up. The UserControl approach works very, very well. (1) My application has a fixed number of tab templates that can be used 0-n times in an application instance. Using UserControls provides flexibility that I wouldn't have had in the big-XAML approach. (2) The new solution seems much more maintainable. File sizes are rational, and each file's contents are intuitive. There are other benefits that I'm sure just aren't occurring to me again. Thanks again for the advice.